# find the largest integer $m$ such that $2^m$ divides $3^{2n+2}-8n-9$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> find the largest integer $m$ such that $2^m$ divides $\space 3^{2n+2}-8n-9$ when $n$ is a natural number.

If the answer was known it will be easy induction.

I started out like this :

$\space 3^{2n+2}-8n-9=9(3^{2n}-1)-8n=9\underbrace{(3^n-1)(3^n+1)}-8n$

Now we have $\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}$ is some integer (sum of GP),or

$ 2|\space 3^n-1$

also we have $3^n+1$ is even ,or

$2|3^n+1....(3)$

From this we conclude $4|(3^n-1)(3^n+1) ...(1)$

Let n be even then $3^n-1=3^{2m}-1=(3^m-1)(3^m+1)$,

by $(1)$ :

$4|(3^m+1)(3^m-1)$ meaning $4|3^n-1...........(2)$

combining $(2),(3)$ we have $8|3^{2n+2}-8n-9$

Similarly i was able to work out the same when $n=2m+1$ by noting that $3^n+1=3^{2m+1}+1$ is divisible by $4$.

I got the largest integer as $3$.

But i am wrong as the MCQ did not have the option $m=3$

how do i proceed.

Note: I have  not learnt about fermat's little theorem

Also i am looking for **Hints**  rather than complete solutions .use of >!  may help

Comment: @hardmath i have done that case plese see

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why not evaluate this epression at $n=1$ and find that $m=6$ then prove by induction it is the largest?

Comment: Are you asking for given $n$, to find largest $m$ with $2^m \mid 3^{2n+2}-8n-9$, or, are you asking for largest $m$ such that $2^m \mid 3^{2n+2}-8n-9$ for all $n$?

Comment: @CSchofx yes that is a good idea will keep in mind,

Comment: @Sil  i am asking for all n ie it should hold for any natural

Comment: The reason I prompted you to reconsider the case $n$ even is because plugging $n=2$ into the formula gives $704 = 64\cdot 11$.  So the observation that $x$ is divisible by $8$ and $y$ is divisible by $8$ is not enough to conclude that the largest power of $2$ that divides $x+y$ is again $8$ (only that it is at least $8$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For $n=1$, it is clear which is the largest power of $2$.  Now consider $(8+1)^{n+1} - [(n+1)\cdot8+1]$ and use binomial expansion to conclude it works for all larger $n$.

Comment: Thank you !answer is $6$ because after simplification $\binom{n+1}{2}8^2+...$ higher terms of 8.right??

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Right. Induction is also an easy way.

Comment: But if you dont know the answer it is difficult isn't it?

Comment: $n=1$ gives you the maximum possible as $2^6$ directly.  Rest is just to check for larger $n$ as i mentioned above.

Comment: @Macavity Write $n=2^tn'$ for some odd natural number $n'$. Also write $(n'+1)=2^{t'}n''$ for some odd natural number $n''$. I guess the answer to this question is $t+t'+5$ (In otherwords $v_2(n)+v_2(\dfrac{n}{2^{v_2(n)}}+1)+5$). I can show that $2^{t+4}$ (which is equal to $v_2(n)+4$) divides that phrase, but I can not go further.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Could you please explain to me how this hint solves the problem? And what is the answer? I can show that if $n=2^tn'$, then $2^{t+3}$ divides both of $9(9^{n}-1)$ and $8n$. Also, $2^{t+4}$ divides non of them. So we can conclude that $2^{t+4}$ divides their sum. So the largest power of $2$, which divides $9(9^n-1)-8n$, should be greater than $2^{t+4}$. Also, I think my guess about the largest power of $2$, which divides $9(9^n-1)-8n$, was wrong.

Comment: @NeoTheComputer If you have nothing related to this answer to add, you should take your comments elsewhere. If you have an alternative approach, post separately. As it stands, it is hard to take your unrelated comments as anything serious, it smacks of just trolling .

Comment: @Macavity I can not understand how your hint solves the problem. Even I can not find the correct answer. Could you please guide me kindly to solve this problem?

Comment: @NeoTheComputer Well, if you follow what i said first and remove the unrelated stuff, i will try helping you. Else, i see no need.

Comment: @Macavity I can see that: $3^{2n+2}-[8n+9]=(8+1)^{n+1} - [(n+1)\cdot8+1]=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{i}8^i=\binom{n+1}{2}8^2+\binom{n+1}{3}8^3+\cdots$. But I do not know how should I continue. Could please guide me kindly? What is the largest power of $2$ which divides $\sum_{i=2}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{i}8^i$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113678/discussion-between-neothecomputer-and-macavity).

Answer (score 2):

In such problems, it's common to check for some small values to see if there's a pattern early on. Let's to do that here:
$$\begin{align}
 n=1&: 3^4 - 8- 9 = 64 = 2^6 \\
 n=2&: 3^6 - 16 - 9 = 704 = 64\cdot 11 = 2^6 \cdot11 \\
 n=3&: 3^8 - 24 - 9 = 6528 = 128\cdot 51 = 2^7 \cdot51 \\
 n=4&: 3^{10} - 32 - 9 = 59008 = 128\cdot 461 = 2^7 \cdot461
 \end{align}$$

So far we are seeing that $2^6 = 64$ does the job. Since you said that you could do induction if you knew the answer, I will let you work it out and add the type with spoilers below:

> If $a_n = 3^{2n+2} - 8n - 9$ then $a_{n+1} = 9a_n + 64(n+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=3^{2n +2}-8n -9$. Then the power series $f (z )=\sum_{k =0}^{\infty }a_k z^k$ can be written as

$$f(z)=\frac{b_0+b_1 z +b_2 z^2}{(1-c_0 z)(1-c_1 z)(1-c_2z)}$$
for some nonnegative integers $b_i$, $c_j$, and furthermore the common divisors of the $b_i$ are divisors of the $a_n$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Unfortunately i have not learnt of power series.Thank you for taking time!